# Execute command on successful SSH connection

Tags: ssh

I would like to execute a command whenever a user establishes a connection to sshd.

I tried setting the command in `/etc/ssh/sshrc` and setting `PermitUserRC no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to prevent users from overriding that.

However, this approach does not work for connections with the `-N` option, which is commonly used for port forwarding connections.

I also tried the solution described in https://askubuntu.com/a/724796/484694, but that also executes the command on unsuccesful login attempts, which is not what I intend.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behaviour using sshd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a small variation of the [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/724796/819150) of using `pam_exec.so`, just using it in the `session` section of the PAM config rather than `auth`, since the `session` modules will only be executed after authentication happens successfully.

Add this to your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /path/to/some/script
```

In the executed script, you can use environment variables such as `$PAM_USER` to access information about the user who is connecting. Especially the environment variable `$PAM_TYPE` is useful to check if the session was opened or closed in the script.

See the man page for [pam_exec(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec) for more details.

Comment: Especially the environment variable `$PAM_TYPE` is useful to check if the session was opened or closed in the script.

Comment: @tmh Thanks! Included that in the answer! Cheers!